# Can't obtain a response from WCF service

Tags: objective-c, json, macos, wcf, web-services

i have a trouble when i try to call a web service made in WCF, this service is calling by Mac os x app.

this is the code

```
soapMessage = @"{name:\"Sergio\"}";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/GSBonoServicios/GSBonoService.svc/HelloWorld"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[soapMessage UTF8String] length:[soapMessage length]];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

The connection is successful but didn't a response, i try implementing some tutorials and I'm looking in Stackoverflow and i find many answers but nothing works, i hope you can help me.

ps. I do not speak much English, but I hope I explained,  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info and sorry for my ignorance but I do not see where I am using soap, and the examples I've found more or less the way you use it, but if you have any other ideas I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: is your wcf service a rest service or a soap one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution the problem was in the service, and the code that works is

```
NSString *name=@"Sergio";
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: name, @"name",
                 nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/Servicio/ServicioEjemplo.svc/HelloWorld"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"applicat ion/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:kNilOptions error:&error];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postdata];
NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postdata
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Thanks